Connections between Jacobian of algebraic curve and its "tropical limit" - Jacobian/Sandpile group of a graph
Recent years there were quite a number of activities on the Jacobian/Sandpile group of a graph. Which is finite abelian group, and its  size is equal to the number of the spanning trees in graph. (See e.g. links here.) It is in some sense analogue ("tropical limit") of the Jacobian of the algebraic curve. There are quite many interesting results and observations supporting that analogy.
Still the relation is somewhat mysterious (at least for me).
My question in general and vague form - is  how to get better intuition on that analogy.  I will try to split it into several sub-questions, but any you are welcome to provide any kind of ideas/references/whatever on that more general and vague question.
Hodge theory perspective. Sandpile group is defined as cokernel on graph Laplacian. Laplacian on curves is defined on infinite dimensional space of functions, while on for graphs it reduces to finite dimensional spaces - functions on nodes.
Question 1: Is there a way to see how finite dimensional space with Z-basis is arising from inifinite dimensional space and to control that cokernel of curve Laplacian would tend to cokernel of the graph Laplacian ?
It might resemble the story of analytic/Redemeister torsion where one can define same thing (torsion):  via Laplacian or via purely finite-dimensional tools and prove that both coincide.
Question 2: Can one see some avatars of "spanning trees" in algebraic setup ? E.g. lift what we see for graphs back to algebraic setup ?
Question 3: Does the order and structure (sizes of p-componets) of Sandpile group can be seen algebraic side ? May be some torsion points on algebraic Jacobian ?
Question 4: Is there generalization of Sandpile group to infinite graphs ? Such that turning back to original setup of Ihara - graphs - are p-adic analogues of modular curves  - via coset representation - factors of Poincare disk  by discrete subgroups. Can interpret Sandpile/Jacobian via p-adic geometry (at least in some sense) ?
